# How to find the similarity between two differently sized distributions?

Tags: python, statistics, signal-processing, radio-transmission

I have two differently sized (different number of samples) waves that are currently stored as lists of numbers. Is there a mathematical formula to measure the similarity between them?

For example:

Wave 1 : 1016 samples

[image: Wave 1 : 1016 samples]

Wave 2 : 512 samples

[image: Wave 2 : 512 samples]

````
``` wave_1 and wave_2 attached in pastebin ```
````

[Link with data for waves 1 and 2](https://pastebin.com/QGGNcWPq)

ie. I have two differently sized lists, that contain a distribution. How do i find if they are similar or not?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by similarity? The answer depends almost entirely on your definition...

Comment: Hi, these waves are two parts of the channel impulse response of a single packet. Since the path taken by both waves must be the same, similarity here means that they have a similar number of peaks, at roughly the same locations and also have the peaks with similar shapes

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [correlation](https://www.jmp.com/en_us/statistics-knowledge-portal/what-is-correlation.html).

If you are using python with pandas, you can visualize the similarities between features (columns) in a dataframe using the seaborn library:

`sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True)`